# Phonegap iOS Splashscreen right but standard loading screen while spinner

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I've got the iOS Splashscreen running with my own Image, set these in Xcode but then if my app is loaded but now is a little time till my website appears and in this gap it shows a spinner and the default phonegap splashscreen. This problem occurs firstly after I tried to rename the project and copy it before this at this place it shows still my own Image and only append the spinner...

I've captured my ipad screen for a better clarification:
https://vimeo.com/91899022

A Screenshot of my project structure: 
(All folders related to the splashscreen)
[image: All folders related to the splashscreen]

Any Ideas on this ?

EDIT: I've just remembered that I changed the way to use icons and splashscreens in xcode to the asset catalog system..

Comment: have you set splashscreen with xcode

Comment: yes, but I also set it in my config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved by the new 3.5.0 update.. thanks to the phonegap team :)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode AppDelegate.m  Increase thread spleep time to set

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];
```

in this method

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
}
```

Comment: you need to remove config.xml splashscreen changes. set default config.xml.now issue is you are try to get splashscreen from www->res->ios->splash. first time you show splash set by xcode and than res-> you need to change splashalso in www->res->ios->splash

Comment: I also set the splashscreen files under `www/res/ios/splash` and under `platforms/ios/appname/Resources/splash`, but what do you mean with "remove config.xml splashscreen changes" ? Actually I set it like this im my config.xml :` <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" /> `

Comment: ok i took out these two lines and paste your line into my AppDelegat.m but doesn't fixed it either, by the way thanks man for your support

Comment: Please remove www/res/ios/splash all .png

Comment: Tried it but doesn't changed anything :/

Comment: what is your phonegap version

Comment: follow this and remove wht i said you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124267/incorrect-www-folder-in-xcode-project-created-by-cordova-3-4-1-0-1-0/23125364?noredirect=1#comment35369731_23125364

Comment: my phonegap version is 3.4.0, I already removed them.. also tried to follow your link but didn't worked for me either. At the moment I have my splashscreen image only in the following directory: `platforms/ios/HelloWorld/Resources/splash`