# Incorrect www folder in xcode project created by cordova 3.4.1-0.1.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I create a new app and add the ios platform. When I open the xcode project the files from www folder are not correct.

Example of my xcode project files that are opening:

Correct way: app_folder / platforms / ios / www

My project: app_folder / www

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq7yt.jpg

This only happens in this version of the cordova. In earlier is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap 3.4.0 stucture will changed if you need www folder what we need to change is in

```
project->staging -> www
```

[image]

Comment: Has anybody seen this in the documentation? No mention in the CLI or in the Platform User Guide, so I was totally puzzled. Thanks for this Amit Prajapati!